# react-hook-form react-select Array Fields wont retain its selected values when remove is clicked

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hook-form, react-select

I got this `react-hook-form` `Array Fields` that contains a `react-select` input element every row, clicking `append` works normally, but when I clicked the `remove` button on any row, all the selected values in all the row turn empty/blank, what went wrong?

Screenshot:
[image]

Here is the `codesandbox` link:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-multiple-usefieldarray-in-a-form-forked-dkez06?file=/src/index.js

Answer (score 0):

Should be `food[${index}].item_select` instead of `food[${index}].name`
In you case you just replace field